# 19.10 Why running: /usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify?

Tags: services, 19.10

Checking for another notify process I noticed `/usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify` is running.

Why is this running? I have not installed evolution and do not wish to receive any evolution notifications -- as far as I know.

I say 'as far as I know' because there could be a good reason to have it running but if so I'd like to know what that reason is.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep evolution-data-server` returns any thing?  Control what is in your autostart.

Comment: @StephenBoston what is your Ubuntu flavor or desktop environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can remember, you use MATE DE. So the answer below is for it.

On clean Ubuntu MATE 19.10 installation the output of `ps` and `htop` give me the clue - `evolution-alarm-notify` is started as dependency of `mate-session`:

```
$ ps xjf
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
  978  1087  1087  1087 ?           -1 Ssl   1000   0:00 mate-session
 1087  1250  1250  1250 ?           -1 Ss    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch mate-session
 1087  1349  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/mate-settings-daemon
 1087  1358  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:01  \_ marco
 1087  1366  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ mate-panel
 1087  1373  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ caja
 1087  1413  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
 1087  1416  1087  1087 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
 1087  1419  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ nm-applet
 1087  1425  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-session/indicator-session-service
 1087  1427  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/polkit-mate/polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1
 1087  1436  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service
 1087  1443  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ mate-maximus
 1087  1446  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/geoclue-2.0/demos/agent
 1087  1450  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ update-notifier
 1087  1459  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ mate-power-manager
 1087  1498  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
 1087  1515  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify
 1087  1539  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
 1087  1588  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
 1087  1609  1087  1087 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet
...
```

The `mate-session` itself is a part of `mate-session-manager` package.
It simply launches `evolution-alarm-notify` from `/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop` (part of `evolution-data-server` package).

Also evolution components start as `systemd --user` services:

```
$ systemctl --user list-units --type service | grep evolution
evolution-addressbook-factory.service loaded active running Evolution address book service                              
evolution-calendar-factory.service    loaded active running Evolution calendar service                                  
evolution-source-registry.service     loaded active running Evolution source registry
```

This is related to the fact that Ubuntu MATE 19.10 uses `indicator-datetime` which is integrated to Evolution. See [*Evolution replaces Thunderbird* part of official Ubuntu MATE 19.10 Release Notes](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-19-10-eoan-ermine-release/).

Comment: Correct. MATE. So I'll give evolution a look. I tried it back before Ubuntu (possible?) and it was far more than I wanted then, but it might be worth another try. I generally like MATE's choices so... Thanks  N0rbert.